# MDX: Limit parent aggregate by child value

Tags: ssas, mdx

My MDX is fledgling at best, and it is a realistic possibility that I don't even know how to phrase my question correctly to search for an answer. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

I have a date/time hierarchy [Dates]:

```
[Work Date].[Dates].[Year].[Quarter].[Month].[Day]
```

What I want to do is return the previous 5 years worth of data, for the month of X (let's assume January):

```
Year         Sub Total
2008         645712.11
2009         848075.43
2010         765802.60
```

However, I'm having trouble restricting the "Year" data, based on the specific month. I have tried this MDX code, but it yields no results at all:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Sub Total] ON 0,
[Work Date].[Dates].[Year] ON 1
FROM (
SELECT [Work Date].[Dates].[Month].&[01] ON 0
FROM [Data Warehouse])
```

If I edit the sub-select I can get a specific year, quarter and month... but I only want to restrict the month portion and not the year. I've looked into using an EXCEPT clause, but I run into the same issue. Does that make any sense? I appreciate any help, and am not opposed to reading long articles if it will further my learning / understanding. Thanks!

Comment: I think your question is a bit confuse, do you want to aggregate 5 years (60 months) back from the selected one? can you explai further?

Comment: I'll try. I want to compare revenue for January of this year, to January of the year before, and the year before that, and the year before that. That way I have a "trend" of January data over the course of 5 years. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your explanation in comments: To get the same child of each hierarchy level you can use the MDX function `COUSIN` ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms145481.aspx) the reference on msdn). As documentation said:

> Returns the child member with the same relative position under a
>   parent member as the specified child member.

so in your case your Date dimension has to be complete without missing months or days, so you can write a query like this (I've tested on AdventureWorks)

```
with member [Measures].[Sub Total] 
as (Cousin([Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2004]&[1], [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember), [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]) , Format_string = 'Currency'

Select {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],[Measures].[Sub Total]  } on 0
,{
  [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2002] 
 ,[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2003]
 ,[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2004]
 } on 1
from [Adventure Works]
```

I've put side by side the total and the sub total for the years. I am considering only these 3 years because they are complete from jan to dec and I can apply cousin operator without problem.

Hope this help!

Comment: I'll have to tweak this a bit to work for me, but I think pointing me to the COUSIN function will do the trick! Thank you for your time and patience. :)